# Rust: wrong borrow order?

Tags: rust

While programming a [Sudoku Solver in Rust](https://github.com/aochagavia/Rust-Sudoku-Solver) I had an issue with some code related to borrowing. While the issue was easy to solve (with a little bit of verbosity), it seemed very strange to me that the compiler didn't accept the first code.

It is difficult to explain what the problem is, so I have made a little example

```
use io::stdio::println;

struct Dog;
impl Dog {
    fn bark(&self, text: &str) {
        println(text);
    }

    fn get_text(&mut self) -> ~str {
        ~"some text"
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut dog = Dog;

    // This causes an error
    dog.bark(dog.get_text());

    // But this is allowed
    let text = dog.get_text();
    dog.bark(text);
}
```

Is this a bug? If not, why does the borrow checker enforce coding this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is a bug: [#6268](https://github.com/mozilla/rust/issues/6268).

The borrow checker doesn't seem to understand the arguments are fully evaluated by the time the original method is called and so thinks the `&mut self` of `get_text` is aliasing with the `&self` of `bark` (and having an aliasing `&mut` pointer is illegal).